# Html.ListBox used to save data to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Maybe a bit awkward title but it's tricky to explain this in one sentence. Sorry.

Anyhow, this is what I've tried to accomplish.

Let's say there's a `Property` model class that holds `ID`, `Name`, and `List`.

I'd want to provide a `TextBox` for name property, `ListBox` for `List` property, and `TextBox` and `Button` for adding strings to list.

```
         ----------
Name     |        | <-textbox
-------- ----------
|item1 |
|...   |
|      | <-listbox
--------
------------ <-textbox for adding
|          | [add] <- button
------------
```

And when I save the model it should save `List` to the property of `Property` model.

I've tried few things, and always something goes wrong. How to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to provide some of your code that you have tried we will be able to help you better - I think it sounds like you want to model bind a `Enumerable<T> eg A List<OfSomething>` ???

Phil Hack as blogged about this here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Its an old post but I think it is still best way to do it??

Comment: Thanks for answering. I took a bit different approach there and... Take a look at this please.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176369/saving-a-model-within-a-model