# Saving a model within a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So, I have this `Property` class that is defined by `ID` `Name` and `DataType`.
`DataType` is already populated with static values, and is being used as a drop down list.

Now when a user picks certain value from the list, `List` value to be precise, application opens additional textbox and button, for populating that list.

Models go like this.

Property model

```
public class Property
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public int DTypeID {get; set;}
    public virtual DType DTypes {get; set;}
}
```

List model

```
public class DList
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int PropertyID {get; set;}
    public string ListValue {get; set;}
}
```

And this is what I've done so far.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="labels tableRow">
            <div class="editor-label tableCell">
                <p>
                    Name
                </p>
                <p>
                    Data Type
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field tableCell">
                <p>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "textEntry" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </p>
                <p>
                    @Html.DropDownList("DTypeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.DTypeID, new { @class = "dropdown", @onchange = "DropDownChange()"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DTypeID)
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="StaticListUI" class="invis">
            <div class="labels tableRow">
                <div class="editor-label tableCell">
                    <p>
                        @*here goes list*@
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field tableCell">
                    <p>
                        @*here goes textbox*@
                        @Html.TextBox("textboxList")
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        @*here goes button*@
                        <button name="button" value="add">Add</button>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


        <p class="labels">
            @*<input type="submit" value="Create" />*@
            <button name="button" value="create">Create</button> |
            <input type="button" value="Back" onClick='javascript:location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Property")";' />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

So in order to capture which button is clicked I did this for my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string button, string textboxList, Property property)
{

    if (button == "add")
    {
        var lastProperty = db.Properties.OrderByDescending(p => p.PropertyID).FirstOrDefault();
        int propID;
        if (lastProperty == null)
        {
            propID = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            propID = 1 + lastProperty.PropertyID;
        }

        DList dList = new DList();

        dList.PropertyID = propID;
        dList.ListValue = textboxList;

        db.DLists.Add(dList);

        return View(property);
    }

    string projectID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["_SelectedProjectID"].ToString();
    int projID = Convert.ToInt32(projectID);
    property.ProjectID = projID;
    property.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    property.DateEdited = DateTime.Now;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Properties.Add(property);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.DTypeID = new SelectList(db.DType, "ID", "Name", property.DTypeID);
    return View(property);
}
```

And the problem is that when I click `Add` button, it still sends a check for `ModelState.IsValid`, which shouldn't. What have I done wrong, or have I done anything right :(

Note: Everything else basically works.

**EDIT**

So I've altered the controller to accept parameters from button clicked differently. But still something is missing...

```
    [ActionName("Create")]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [AcceptParameter(Name = "button", Value = "add")]
    public ActionResult Create_Add(string textboxList)
    {
        var lastProperty = db.Properties.OrderByDescending(p => p.PropertyID).FirstOrDefault();
        int propID;
        if (lastProperty == null)
        {
            propID = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            propID = 1 + lastProperty.PropertyID;
        }

        DList dList = new DList();

        dList.PropertyID = propID;
        dList.ListValue = textboxList;

        db.DLists.Add(dList);
        db.SaveChanges();



        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [AcceptParameter(Name="button", Value="create")]
    public ActionResult Create(Property property)
    {
        string projectID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["_SelectedProjectID"].ToString();
        int projID = Convert.ToInt32(projectID);
        property.ProjectID = projID;
        property.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        property.DateEdited = DateTime.Now;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Properties.Add(property);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.DTypeID = new SelectList(db.DType, "ID", "Name", property.DTypeID);
        return View(property);
    }


    public class AcceptParameterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            var req = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
            return req.Form[this.Name] == this.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The !ModelState.IsValid is most likely caused by the model binding - probably on the Property parameter.  You could make a call to ModelState.Clear() just before returning the view?

Comment: You did something wrong (there is very strange that two different actions - "add" and "create" invoke single action method). Could you describe process that you programming?

Comment: As I've explained the existence of `Property` and `DList`

When user starts to create a new `Property` it shows textbox for `Name` and dropdown for `DataType`, and from that dropdown list generated from `DType` selects `List` value, a textbox appears that allows saving values to `DList` model. That would be 'textboxList` and `Add` button. When add button is clicked it should only add a value to `DList` and allow adding more values. Then when user clicks `Create` it should save created `Property`. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean something is missing? Whats happening, is it correctly accessing each `ActionResult`?

Comment: No it is not. Still not... Only accessing `Create` method for `Property` and not for `DList`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `db.DLists.Add(dList);` but do don't save it in the database, you just return the view. You could put `db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;` above the `db.DLists.Add(dList);` and see if that works, however I think it should look like this:

```
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
db.DLists.Add(dList);
db.SaveChanges();
return View(property);
```

You may want to turn the Validate On Save back on before the return.

**Update**
Perhaps you could try this:

```
@{
    var textBoxData = form.find('input[name="textboxList"]').val();
}
<input type="button" value="Add"  title="Add"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create_Add", "Controller", new { textboxList = textBoxData })'" />
```

Comment: Tried it. Still checks the same... :(

Comment: Are you sure that expression button == "add" is true when you click add? Could you set breakpoint there and check it?

Comment: I checked and you are right, it doesn't pass that expression...
How do I get the event on different buttons clicked then ?
This is the way I've used once before, but in a less complicated case... And it worked.

I could perhaps call another form from the click ?
`<button name="button" type="button" onclick="$('#addForm').submit()">Add</button>`

Comment: I've seen it done like your talking about, but the controller still had multiple `Actions` and depending on what button you clicked it would call the corresponding action. The `Actions` have the custom attribute `[MultiButtonFormSubmit(ActionName = "UpdateDeleteCancel", SubmitButton = "Update")]` above them. I don't have the code for that attribute though, perhaps you could google it.

Comment: I just altered it that way. Still getting the same check up on regular `Create` action. No idea what I'm doing wrong at this point. :(
New controller is in **edit** of question.

Comment: @user1407758 is you put a breakpoint at `db.DLists.Add(dList);` is `dList.ListValue` null?

Comment: @user1407758 Comment out your `AcceptParameter` on both actions and try my update, I've never done it that way, but I think it may work. Otherwise thats all I got.

Comment: One really stupid question. My form `@using (Html.BeginForm())` is starting like that how should I access it with `form.find()` ? I've tried adding the ID but nothing...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15968/discussion-between-user1407758-and-garrett-fogerlie)