# "Predict" next model ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sheesh...

I think this can be done but I just can't figure it out at the moment.

So I've created this app, that's working fine. But for some reason (too long to explain sorry) I would need to predict next ID to come from data table.

Note that last id + 1 will not work. I've tried this.

```
var lastProperty = db.Properties.OrderByDescending(p => p.PropertyID).FirstOrDefault();
int propID;
if (lastProperty == null)
{
    propID = 1;
}
    else
{
    propID = 1 + lastProperty.PropertyID;
}
```

And as long as properties don't get deleted it works...
As soon as one is deleted, it messes up of course, since lets say we delete `6th Property`,
last one will be `5th` now, and with that code we'll get `6` `5(last one) + 1`, and I save my model related to `Property` with `PropertyID` `6` which I got from that code, and next `Property` will be 7 since database still remembers that 6 existed and was deleted... Model I intended to have same `PropertyID` as THAT last `Property` will not have it, and it'll fail...

Also, I can't add this AFTER saving `Property`, I realize that might seem as a solution but it's not. It has to be predicted.

Thank you... Please help...

**UPDATE**

This is the use case I'm trying to accomplish.

`Property` model with `ID` `Name` `DataType` properties.
`List` model with `ID` `ListValue` `PropertyID` properties.

When new `Property` is created user types in the `Name`, and from premade dropdown list for `DataType` selects a value, if that value is `List`, it opens additional form that contains a listbox, textbox and a button (`add_Button`). User types in the value in a textbox, and clicks the `add_Button` to add it to `List`.

Listbox is populated from `List` model, and `add_Button`, saves values from textbox to `ListValue` property of `List`, also as you've seen, I'm trying to manually add `PropertyID` to `List` by predicting it's value...

Then, upon finishing adding all the elements wanted through textbox, by clicking `Create` button, `Property` is then saved.

Hope this was clear enough.

Comment: Just as a side note: You might have problem with this approach if this is a multithreaded or multi client environment and more than one threads / clients are updating that table. Because some other code might add/delete a row to/from the table after you got the identity value but before you insert the data.

Comment: Regardless of the "solution" you decide on I can promise you that it will be the cause of a number of recurring issues down the road. Whatever the application or business process which is forcing you to need the next ID has an underlying problem that you should fix rather than searching for a band aid.

Comment: I realize that it's an issue, but just no way around it... I need to save multiple list items to a model that needs to be later sorted by property id while in process of creating that same property... that's kinda troublesome...
For more info look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176369/saving-a-model-within-a-model - but i've resolved that part already and just need this now...

Comment: "but i've resolved that part already" --- seems like you've done it wrong. There is always a solution that doesn't require you to predict next value. Without even a single exception.

Comment: Possibly... I just haven't grasped it. Also I haven't asked the question to listen to complaints but to learn, if you don't mind...

Comment: Just a simple question. Could you please share why you want the Next ID ? what are you going to do with that ? We will addresss the issue from there.

Comment: I've updated my question, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When need to know what your primary key values are going to be before committing to the Db you could use a uniqueidentifier (GUID) as the Pk for your `Property` and therefore as the Fk for your `List` entity.  That way you can create it your self and it'll always be unique on committal.

Comment: I've done just that yesterday and it works nicely. :)
Since your answer is what I used I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to know the current state of the identity column:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Table')
```

Comment: I should've mention, I'm doing this in Entity Framework Code First, so LINQ or something might be better, since I doubt I could use that, or could I???

Comment: You can use ExecuteStoreCommand. There is no built-in way to do this, partially because this is RDBMS specific (which EF is not).

Comment: Could I bother you with an example, I haven't done that before.

Answer (score 0):

You mention Entity Framework, have you tried adjusting your model?

`StoreGeneratedPattern` can be adjusted to allow automatic update of your local model when you store to the database.

Comment: I've tried to make several adjustments so I avoid this, but no luck. I'll read more on `StoreGeneratedPattern` Thank you.